# Most Secure way to Attach Wires to Header?

Tags: headless, wiring

I am constructing a portable device (a tool the enhance the quality of life for a blind user) but, alas, because it is portable, it must be able to survive the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune.

Alas, when testing/building the electronics, I couldn't help but notice that the connection housings I'm using [these things](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&site=us&keywords=A26962-ND&x=9&y=13&formaction=on), are not that secure.

They WILL be housed, but a good bump/pull at one of the (kind of) exposed wires could end the usefulness of the device.

(The guy this is intended for has a fully working mind, but massive brain damage, so cant *physically* fix it.)

Would someone be so kind as to tell me the best way to securely attach wires to the header of the pi?

I can solder... but I don't know if it's good for the pi.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a standard 26-pin ribbon cable, like this one:

[image]

This won't come loose by accident.  If you need additional strain-relief, just put a loop in the cable and fix it to the case - that will stop any tugs being passed on to the pi.

If you haven't got one of these 26-pin cables, maybe you can get an old 40-pin printer cable and chop the plastic down to size.  If you don't need all the 26 pins, which you probably don't, then you can use a ribbon cable with fewer connections instead.

Don't solder anything to the pi.

Comment: Is the application of heat dangerous to the pi?

Answer (score 0):

Soldering is definitely the most secure connection you can come up with. There's no inherent problem to doing it to the Pi, but it is somewhat permanent though. The important things to watch out for are that you don't accidentally touch the iron to any place else on the circuit board. It may be worth also taking a break between soldering each pin to avoid any possibility of heat damage.

Alternative to soldering directly to the pi, [full 26 pin GPIO header blocks](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2x-Raspberry-PI-GPIO-26-pin-female-socket-connector-header-/380708889639) seat very securely as they involve all pins, but would let you make something that you could disconnect if necessary. Soldering is still required though.